# SQL Server - Stored Procedure Insert Duplicate record at same time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Why Stored Procedure insert this SP in duplicate record?
But its just happen for 5-6 case from 100 case.
this SP insert duplicate record at same time, its like 2-4 record.
How to avoid this issue? 
I use ASP.Net MVC for the code, and using AJAX for the POST.
I Have Stored Procedure like this

```
DECLARE 
@PromotionID nvarchar(40)='',
@LoginName nvarchar(200),
@PromotionApplyStatusID int=0,
@PromotionCode nvarchar(40)='',
@ClaimTimestamps datetime2= null,
@RemarkText nvarchar(MAX)='',
@BetIDText nvarchar(MAX)='',
@TransIDText nvarchar(MAX)='',
@ShippingAddressText  nvarchar(MAX)='',
@PrizeAmount decimal=0,
@TurnOver int=0,
@Currency nvarchar(40)='',
@result int=0,
@AccountID int=0

SET @AccountID = (SELECT AccountID FROM MemberAccount WHERE MemberID = (SELECT MemberID FROM Member WHERE WebsiteID=2 AND Member.MemberName=@LoginName))

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SystemPromotionDetail WHERE PromotionID=@PromotionID AND AccountID=@AccountID AND PromotionApplyStatusID=0)
BEGIN
    DELETE SystemPromotionDetail 
    WHERE PromotionID=@PromotionID AND AccountID=@AccountID AND PromotionApplyStatusID=0
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SystemPromotionDetail WHERE PromotionID=@PromotionID AND AccountID=@AccountID AND PromotionApplyStatusID=0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SystemPromotionDetail
    (
        PromotionID,
        AccountID,
        PromotionApplyStatusID,
        PromotionCode,
        ClaimTimestamps,
        RemarkText,
        BetIDText,
        TransIDText,
        ShippingAddressText,
        PrizeAmount,
        TurnOver,
        Currency
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @PromotionID ,
        @AccountID,
        @PromotionApplyStatusID,
        @PromotionCode,
        @ClaimTimestamps,
        @RemarkText,
        @BetIDText,
        @TransIDText,
        @ShippingAddressText,
        @PrizeAmount,
        @TurnOver,
        @Currency
    )
END
```

Comment: It sounds like a race condition.  One execution of this code can only insert one condition.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff has mentioned, your SP will execute once so perhaps your AJAX (or server) request is being executed multiple times due to a certain condition. If you could post some additional code it may be easier to identify if this is the case.